# How to use Optional to check null values in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have a class containing nested and inner classes. And in some program, i am check for the null values of the object using equal operator in the legacy java way. The following is my code snippet:

```
class Outer {
    Nested nested;
    Nested getNested() {
        return nested;
    }
}
class Nested {
    Inner inner;
    Inner getInner() {
        return inner;
    }
}
class Inner {
    String foo;
    String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And here is how i am doing the null checks on the reference variables:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
if (outer != null && outer.nested != null && outer.nested.inner != null) {
    System.out.println(outer.nested.inner.foo);
}
```

I know this can also be done using the Optional class of java 8, but i am not getting a way for doing the same above particular scenario.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The follwoing code worked well for me:

```
Optional.of(new Outer())
    .map(Outer::getNested)
    .map(Nested::getInner)
    .map(Inner::getFoo)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: and that's good code, you can totally answer your own questions here, even accept them. +1

Answer (score 6):

I highly suggest you watch the recent [Devoxx Belgium presentation "Optional - The Mother of All Bikesheds" by Stuart Marks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14). Stuart is describing what was the initial intent, best practices and bad practices using it.

In particular using Optional in fields, quoting from the presentation slide:

> - Why Not Use Optional in Fields?
>
>   - More a style issue than a correctness issue
>   - use of Optional in fields often arises from slavish desire to eliminate nullable fields.
>   - remember, eliminating nulls isn't a goal of Optional
> - Using Optional in fields..
>
>   - creates another object for every field
>   - introduces a dependent load from memory on every field read
>   - clutters up your code
>   - to what benefit? ability to chain methods?

To your example in particular:

1. why `outer != null` check? it's just got created!
2. if `Nested` instance needs to be part of `Outer` and `Inner` part of `Nested` have them part of the constructors and guard with some `@NotNull` code or check programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for linking to my talk!

Comment: Thanks for bringing such insight to the java community!